# Adding options for your application to the Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, contextmenu

You know how when you right click on something in explorer there are options for your antivirus, ZIP archive manager, etc?

I was wondering how one might add options for their own application to the context menu. After a failed search for the answer on the internet, I came here.

Thanks for your help.

(I doubt it's relevant but I use C++ and Visual Studio 2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a shell extension handler, a context menu extension handler in your case.  Covered well in [this series of tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx), part 1 talks about menus and how to install and debug these handlers.